# fetch images in document library and show slideshow

Tags: sharepoint-online

in my document set is haveing document library called event1 from that library i want to fetch images and event name and place and time and detaileddescription
using rest api and scripteditor webpart

can any one please help me out 
thanks&regards

Comment: Ideally document libraries contain document sets. Have you mis typed the question?

Answer (score 1):

You question is not very well formed.
But, if I understood you correct, you want to create webpart slide show?

If so, first create Picture library. Than create new web part on a page and under the categories of webpart types choose **Media and content**.
There choose *Picture Library Slideshow Web Part*. Than edit that webpart and add your Picture library as origin.